# Unable to run executable jar for grails 6 application

Tags: gradle, grails

I am following the documentation here - https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/deployment.html to create and run executable jar with grails 6 and java 11.

Steps to reproduce:

1. create a new app

   `grails create-restapi myapp`
2. assemble it

   `./gradlew assemble`
3. execute the jar

   `java -jar build/libs/myapp-0.1-plain.jar`

But I get following message instead:

`no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/myapp-0.1-plain.jar`

Even after adding following in the build.gradle as per other posts

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'myapp.Application'
    }
}
```

I get following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class myapp.Application
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/boot/config/GrailsAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer from an issue here:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/13055

I should have run './gradlew bootWar' instead of './gradlew assemble' as opposed to the documentation!

java -jar build/libs/myapp-0.1-plain.war runs fine after than.